# Processing QuerySet result

Tags: django

I have the following code to validate user credentials

```
userDetail = User.objects.using (settings.DATABASE_CONF).filter (status=1, email_id=emailId, password=password).values
        ('user_id' , 'email_id'  )
```

Im able to validate it and get the result. I want to Print user_id into my console and also set it in session object. I tried

```
if userDetail :
```

But it returns true even if the userDetail list is empty.

I tried

```
for n in userDetail:
```

It says "'instancemethod' object is not iterable"

How to validate it is empty or null and take the value of user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't split a method call before the parentheses. What you have done there is assign userDetail to the *method* `values`, not the result. Bring the parens back onto the previous line - if you must split, you can do it after the open paren.